# Estimate the speed of BLDC motor using back-EMF constant

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, rms

I want to mesure the speed of BLDC motor using back-EMF constant, \$Ke=Vrms/rpm\$, so the speed is \$rpm=Vrms/ke\$.

What I want to know is how to get the Vrms? Suppose I have DC supply=40 V and the duty cycle = 80% does the \$Vrms = 0.8*40=32V\$? Or the \$Vrms=40*0.8/sqrt(3)=18.47V\$?

**Edit:**
i already know how to mesure the speed using this equation
 \$rpm=F*60/p\$
but instead I want to estimate the speed using back-EMF constant.

Comment: surely it's far easier with a BLDC to time the transitions of the back EMF?

Comment: Neil ,I didn't understand what you said ?

Comment: Its a sinewave. Its frequency is a much better measure of the speed than voltage will ever be. Use a frequency meter and divide by the number of pole pairs. (*60 for RPM)

Comment: yes i know, but i want to use it in application where i compare the speed of the motor under load and the desired speed when applying PWM

Comment: That's silly, you can't electronically commutate a BLDC without knowing how fast the poles are passing.

Comment: Chris yes you can estimate the speed with the Bemf constant, source:https://things-in-motion.blogspot.com/2019/05/understanding-bldc-pmsm-electric-motors.html

Comment: @Mourad such a scheme can only *estimate*, which is grossly inferrior to actually *measuring* the commutation rate.  In your question, you used the word "determine" and now you admit your analog scheme will only estimate, which makes it a bad choice compared to the actual *measurement* implicit in the very act of commutation.  And if as your comments suggest you want to study the behavior under load, then accuracy from a deterministic *timing* measurement is especially key.

Comment: So you suggest replacing "determine" with "estimate" in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found the solution.
  thus, i will answer my own question
Some motor spec use \$ke= Vrms/rpm \$(because when calculating the Ke they used the VRMS volatge and not the peak voltage) so in my example the \$Vrms=40*0.8/sqrt(2)\$
but most motor manufactures use \$Ke= Vpeak/rpm\$ so in my example \$Vpeak=40*0.8\$ 
and in order to calculate the rpm i need to take into consideration the voltage drop and the losses therefore the actual speed will be 
\$rpm=Dutycyle*(Vsupply-Vdrop)/Ke -(Ploss/Tloss)\$

with \$(Ploss/Tloss)\$ is the speed reduction brought about by the power and subsequent torque required to be produced by a motor to overcome friction, windage and core losses.
source:https://things-in-motion.blogspot.com/2019/05/understanding-bldc-pmsm-electric-motors.html

Comment: As explained in comments this is a weak solution to the problem.  To drive the motor via electronic commutation the driver has to measure the actual timing of pole passing, and the pole count is a constant, so you readily know the actual instantaneous RPM as well - *without* the error this amplitude scheme will suffer.

Comment: as i said in the comment, i'm actually measuring the speed of the motor with the equation rpm=f*60/p but i also want to comapre it with the equation above.i don't why you downvote my answer i think my question is clear ''Determine the speed of BLDC motor using back-EMF constant''

Comment: This is a foolish and inaccurate way to measure speed, when there's an implicitly accurate one available in the act of commutation itself.

Comment: well Chris i can not explain to you what's the hole project because it has many details for a comment, all i want is to determine the speed using back-EMF constant and not the frequency and the pole pairs. maybe the only thing i should correct it is to replace "determine" with "estimate" in the question